# AWS Organization - Why do I get "You have exceeded the allowed number of AWS accounts." error even though I've only added 2 accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations, aws-iam-identity-center

When I try to add a new account to my Organization using either the Web UI or the AWS cli, I keep getting this error. I checked the quotas and I should be able to create 10 accounts. But however as of now I only have 2 accounts. It's the managing account and another account.
This is the error I get when trying to use the AWS cli for this,

```
An error occurred (ConstraintViolationException) when calling the CreateAccount operation: You have exceeded the allowed number of AWS accounts.
```

I tried searching for a solution everywhere but it says to contact AWS technical support. But the problem is since I'm on **Basic** support tier, technical support isn't available for me and currently I'm not capable to afford the **Developer** support tier. I wouldn't be able to purchase it until my request for Startup credits with my startup enabling program is accepted. Even then I don't if that I could use those credits towards a support plan. So I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Did it ask you to contact Technical Support or Customer Service? The Customer Service team handles billing and account-related queries and you don't need to subscribe to Support to contact them. See: [AWS Support and Customer Service Contact Info | Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)

Comment: Are you AWS Accounts relatively new (eg a few days)? They have restrictions in place on new accounts to prevent fraud, and there might be tighter restrictions on the number of accounts you can create at the moment.

Comment: Great advice from @JohnRotenstein, as customer service questions are off-topic here - see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)